# Textbox value converts to asterisk symbols like password edit field

Tags: blackberry

I took one custom text box image, in that text box I want to show "Enter password" and when I focus on to that text box field and enter any charectors it converts to asterisk symbols like password edit field.

I want like this below Image:

[image: password Box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible by only overriding `paint(..)` of the `Editfield`. May be following steps can achieve the desired behaviour:

- Store original text to a local variable.
- Generate fake text depending on focus status, original text etc.
- Call `super.paint(..)`, it will paint the field with fake text.
- Use `setText(..)` to set original text back.

Draft implementation:

```java
class MyEditField extends EditField {
    private final static String INIT_TEXT = "Enter Password";

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        String originalText = getText();
        String fakeText = originalText;

        if (originalText.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            fakeText = isFocus() ? originalText : INIT_TEXT;
        } else {
            fakeText = "";
            for (int i=0;i<originalText.length();i++) {
                fakeText += '*';
            }
        }

        setText(fakeText);
        super.paint(graphics);          
        setText(originalText);
    }
}
```

*Above code doesn't paint a border.*

We need to set a monochrome font for the problem you have mentioned in comment. Here is a sample code:

```java
MyEditField me = new MyEditField();

try {
    Font font = null;
    FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
    for (int i=0;i<fontFamily.length; i++) {
        if (fontFamily[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Courier New")) {
        font = fontFamily[i].getFont(FontFamily.SCALABLE_FONT, 
                            Font.getDefault().getHeight());
        me.setFont(font);
        break;
    }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: I got the solution from your code but if i give password as numbers like:1245678921(something) then I got space between the cursor and characters. check it once.

Comment: Don't know how to solve this problem. But no why this problem happens. When the EditField calculates text width using 'getAdvance(..)', the result is returned for original text. And if we don't use Monochrome font (fixed width) then this problem occurs. So to get rid of this problem we have to set a monochrome font to that field. I have edited the answer for this. Have a look.

Comment: Read "no" as "know" (typo) in the 2nd line of the previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: I create My own CustomPasswordField for "password", "Re-Enter Password" and "Pincode",etc., at the time of ask this question; I honorably accept your answer because you gave the nice code and my requirement is 97% correct by your code; Keep it up;

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use a [PasswordEditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/PasswordEditField.html).

Implement it just like any LabelField, and it will do what you need.

---

I see you wanted the background text too - I would use drawText() from within the paint() method to draw that. The other answer that shows a full implementation by using EditField is also good.

Comment: The PasswordEditField does exactly what you want.  Why reinvent the wheel?